# Zerotier cli command giving error "missing port and zerotier-one.port not found" in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, zerotier

I downloaded zero tier from their [website](https://www.zerotier.com/download/) using the following command:

```
curl -s https://install.zerotier.com | sudo bash
```

Whenever I try to use the zerotier cli it's giving the following error:
"zerotier-cli: missing port and zerotier-one.port not found in /var/lib/zerotier-one"

[image: screenshot]

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try

`zerotier-one -d`

start the service
before you use zerotier-cli

Comment: this one worked for me combined with https://github.com/zerotier/ZeroTierOne/issues/1050

Answer (score 5):

First, review the whole service log with:

```
journalctl -u zerotier-one.service
```

Good chances you'll see that the 9993 port is already allocated by some other service (e.g. docker, etc.), which might look like that:

```
/usr/sbin/zerotier-one: fatal error: cannot bind to local control interface port 9993
```

If so, then simply change the default port, e.g. to 9994, by generating */var/lib/zerotier-one/local.conf* with the following content:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "primaryPort": 9994
  }
}
```

Comment: For me worked after  changing the port number ( executed command  `zerotier-one -d` too after port modification )